# Which linear model appropriate for these data

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, image-processing

I have a data set from image analysis which has a hierarchical mixed design: several (around ten per group) images were analysed belonging to one of several experimental group. For each image, there are several thousands of readouts (area sized in pixels). Image is therefore a random effect, experimental group is the fixed effect.

Since the readouts are numbers of pixels of an area from image analysis (one image = one batch), they are always positive and the data is not normally distributed. The log transformed distribution of the data looks more or less as follows:

[image]

Each line corresponds to a single image.

The imprecise experimental question is whether areas in group A are different from areas in group B. More strictly, I ask whether the experimental group has an effect on the distribution of the measured areas.

My question is what model is it correct to use in such a situation, or how to transform the data to use a "simple" model (nlme or lme4).

Comment: I'm going to throw an idea that might not be statistically pertinent if I did not understand the question: could you not just use an LME and compute the null distributions (of your coefficients of interest) with permutations?

Comment: OK, maybe I could :-) How would I do that?